# Twitter, get all Tweets of the last 24 hours

Tags: java, twitter, tweets

I'm working on an application that needs to show all tweets of a certain user made in the last 24 hours. Is there a convenient way using the REST-API? I would like to avoid some kind of caching mechanism using the [timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline). Thank you :)

Comment: Why wont using `since_id` parameter work for you?

Comment: since_id won't accept time as a parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you can do with the Twitter REST API is something like this :

```
Timeline resTimeline = downloadTimeline();
Tweet lastTweet = resTimeline.get(resTimeline.size() - 1);

while (lastTweet is younger than 24 hours) {
    TweetID lastTweetID = lastTweet.id;
    Timeline bufferTimeline = downloadTimeline(max_id = lastTweetID);
    resTimeline.addAll(bufferTimeline);
    lastTweet = resTimeline.get(resTimeline.size() - 1);
}

return resTimeline;
```

Comment: Thanks. The `max_id` parameter helped to solve this. Now, I just need some container that is filled in the front and trimmed at the end.